# Allow Empty Input But Run Custom Validation Rule - CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've had the most frustrating time trying to play with CakePHP 2's validation mechanisms. I am trying to allow for an input to be empty, yet still run a custom validation rule. However, if I use `"allowEmpty" => true`, it bypasses my custom validation rule.

**Code**

```
    // in $validate array
    ...
    'company_role' => array(
        'reqIfFieldValueEquals' => array(
            'rule' => array('reqIfFieldValueEquals', 'individual_or_company', 'company'),
            'message' => 'You must provide your role with the company!',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => true
        ),
    ),
    ...

// my custom validation rule which will NOT run! >:(
public function reqIfFieldValueEquals($field, $compare_field, $value) {
    $fieldValue = false; 
    foreach ($field as $name => $val) {
        $fieldValue = $val; 
    }
    $valueToCheck = $this->data[$this->name][$compare_field];
    if ($valueToCheck === $value) {
        return !empty($fieldValue); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Q** How in the world can I allow for an empty input, yet still run my custom validation rule?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need validation on empty input, but can you try to disable allow input, and simply return true in the validation rule if the input is empty?